# To Display an Alert Notification by hiding the registration form

Tags: php, jquery

I have two php files one is register.php in which i have html form  and i used jquery to validate it. and on process.php i have php code to insert the data in resgistration table in database if it username don't exit..

i want to show the alearts in paragraph tag or div tag by hiding the html form in register.php.
these alearts are
1. username already exists
2. user registation is sucessfull
3. registration unsucessfull.

Please take a look on process.php 
this part

```
if($show>0)

                {
                die("user exits");

                } 



if($query)
                die("registration successfull");
                else
                die("registration not successful");
```

I want to show these alerts on register.php file by hiding the form and diplaying that notifications...

here is the register.php code in short..

```
<script src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script >

$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formjs").validate({
                rules:{
                    fname:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength:5,
                        maxlength:23
                    },
                    lastname:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength:5,
                        maxlength:23
                    },
                  and so onoooooooooooo



   some part of form

</div>

            <form id="formjs" name="formjs" method="post" action="process.php" >

                <p>

                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""  />
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="lastnamme">LastName *</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"  />
                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="username">Email Address *</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"  id="username" />
                </p>

                <p>
```

and here is the process.php full code...

```
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['username']))
                {

                $ftname=$_POST['fname'];
                $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
                $gender=$_POST['gender'];
                $bday=$_POST['day'];
                $byear=$_POST['year'];
                $bmonth=$_POST['month'];
                $username=$_POST['username'];
                $password=$_POST['password1'];
                $contact=$_POST['contact'];

                include('config.php');
                $Query = mysql_query("SELECT userid from Account where userid = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
                $show=mysql_num_rows($Query);
                if($show>0)

                {
                die("user name already exits");

                } 

                else 
                {
                $query=mysql_query(" insert into Account (firstname,lastname,gender,bday,byear,bmonth,userid,password,contactno) values 
                            ('$ftname','$lastname','$gender','$bday','$byear','$bmonth','$username','$password','$contact')") or die(mysql_error());
                if($query)
                die("registration sucessfull");
                else
                die("registration not sucessfull");
                //echo "<center>Thank you! You are now a member!</center>";

                }
                }

                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i will suggest you to instead of checking **user exist** functionality on submit click. you can write a  callback which will check that username /email already exist or not. so this will become more easy to you to save successful data.

one more suggestion, instead of **hiding the html form in register.php** you can place the validation on each field so it will become more easy.